# Using UNNEST in a custom Postres Query in Google Data Studio

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I have a table that has multiple values saved in an array in one column. (I know that this is not normalized/optimal database structure.) I'm trying to write a query that can create rows for each value in the array. The query below is working for me in Tableau but not Google Data Studio (I'm using a custom query with the PostgreSQL connector). Are there any limitations/different syntax requirements when using UNNEST in Data Studio?

```
SELECT
    e.name as event_name,
    e.date as event_date,
    l.full_name as leader_name,
    p.full_name as participant_name

    FROM
            (
            SELECT
                event_id,
                user_id,
                UNNEST(participants_ids)::INTEGER as participant_id 
                from event_reports 
            ) r

        LEFT JOIN events e ON r.event_id = e.id
        LEFT JOIN users l ON r.user_id = l.id
        LEFT JOIN users p ON r.participant_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query should probably have a lateral join:

```
SELECT e.event_id,
       e.user_id,
       p.participant_id
FROM event_reports AS e
     CROSS JOIN
     LATERAL unnest(e.participants_ids) AS p(as participant_id)
```

With a lateral join, you can reference something from the left side of the join on the right side. The cross join combines each `event_reports` row with rach participant ID that belongs to that row.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looking at the documentation for Lateral Join, I believe you're correct that that is what I'm looking for. I tried using the query you suggested, but it didn't work. I think this is more of an issue with Data Studio than with the query, though. I tried stripping the query down to `SELECT UNNEST(r.participants_ids) FROM event_reports r` but even that query returned an error when put into a Data Studio report. The query is successful, but the report returns an error.

Comment: I'd like to help, if you give me details about "didn't work".

Comment: Thanks! Again, I'm working in Data Studio using a custom query on their Postgres connector, and I suspect this might just be an issue on that end.

I'm using the query:
`SELECT UNNEST(participants_ids) as id FROM event_reports`

The query connection seems successful and gives me a data source with columns id | record count. But when creating a report with a table using the id metric, the report table returns an error message: 
"System Error
Data Studio has encountered a system error.

Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Error ID: d63f4148: